# Python Tensorflow DQN Next Steps

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I can't figure out the next steps for my Deep Q Network. I'm trying to optimize bus routes. I have a distance matrix and data on stop popularity.

The `distance` matrix is a 2d array with all of the `stop`s detailing the distance between them. If there are 4 stops, it will look like the following:

```
distance=np.array[[0, stop1-stop2, stop1-stop3, stop1-stop4],
                 [stop2-stop1, 0, stop2-stop3, stop2-stop4],
                 [stop3-stop1, stop3-stop2, 0, stop3-stop4],
                 [stop4-stop1, stop4-stop2, stop4-stop3, 0]]
```

The `rewards` matrix is simply:

```
(1/distance) * (percent of total riders who get on and off at specific stop)
```

This is to ensure that stops with short distances between them and high numbers of riders have the highest reward values.

I have made classes for each `stop`. These show how many people are waiting at each stop, and updates the stops with more people regularly. When the bus 'reaches' a stop, it's `waiters` value becomes `0`, and therefore it's reward becomes `0` until more people arrive.

I set up the model with the following code:

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    # Current game states. Rows of the rewards matrix corresponding to   the agent's current stop. Inputs to neural network.
    observations = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[None, num_stops])

    # Actions. A number from 0-number of stops, denoting which stop the agent traveled to from its current location.
    actions = tf.placeholder('int32',shape=[None])

    # These are the rewards received by the agent for making its decisions. +1 if agent 'wins' the game (gets system score to 0 (this will only happen if bus stops are not updated periodically))
    rewards = tf.placeholder('float32',shape=[None])  # +1, -1 with discounts


# Model


    # This is first layer of neural network, takes the observations tensor as input and has '200' hidden layers. This number is arbitrary, I'm not sure how to adjust it for peak performance.
    Y = tf.layers.dense(observations, 200, activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

From here I'm not sure what to do. I want to run the neural network in batches, not updating the weights after every bus action (moving from one stop to another). Instead, I want to wait until a full 'game' is completed, e.g. a predetermined number of actions bus takes before game ends. If the game has been won, e.g. the bus has visited every stop in a predetermined time, a reward will be given. I am thinking of using 1 to keep things simple. Earlier actions will be discounted by a discount rate.

I am thinking this way because I want the agent to see the long-term effects of its individual actions. I saw this in a paper about an agent learning to play pong, and am trying to implement a similar agent to play my system. Thank you in advance for any help.